# Nested ngFor and trackBy, comparsion of arrays

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have a bigger project there I have 4 nested *ngFor. So the creation is arround 200 lines long, I think sharing wouldn´t help so I explain it as good as I can.
**The problem** is after refreshing the object, the elements get destroyed and recreated. Which leeds to a performance issue (Nothing I matter about just 0,5 seconds) and an scrolling back to the top. And this is my problem I dont want this happening.

The array:

```
 array[0-X] = For Paginator
 array[X][1-3] = contains 3 columns // #Column
 array[X][X][1-9] = divides the column in 9 blocks // #InfoBlock
 array[X][X][X][1-X] = the content of the single blocks // #Info
```

After the creation, the user is able to move only the #Info element over his settings wherever he want.

As example moving a #Info to a different #InfoBlock. Via subscription I save the change to the database and **reload the whole array.**

Like this:

```
this.pageinator = result;
```

Now it destryoys the divs and creates them new, this leads my layout to scroll to top. I tried trackby, but cause of the whole array is overwritten it won't work.

**The question:**  Is there a way to comparison 2 arrays and just take the changes to the previous one. I know I could not reload the data, but this can cause problems because the software isn´t used by just 1 user.

Edit: An example

```
array[0][1][1][1] = "Content X"
array[0][1][2][2] =  undefined
// After reloading
array[0][1][1][1] =  undefined
array[0][1][2][2] =  "Content X"
// Now I want Angular to just change this 2 elements, cause the others stay the same.
```

**Edit 2:**
I have found out that sometimes:

```
this.pageinator = result;
```

Automaticly only take the changes. This happens in 1 out of 10 times.

Comment: Use trackBy and just don't recreate the array, but instead clear and fill the previous array with the new elements.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Is there a good and easy way to do that ? The only thing which comes in my mind is to loop trough both arrays, lock for changes and then push, delete, change accordingly. And on every delete, push I would have to rerun the loop. This leads with 10 000 + elements to a huge loading increase.

Comment: Angulars IterableDiffer should provide you with the delta. `NgFor` uses it.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Will have a look into it ty.

Comment: `NgFor` uses it internally. You can get from there how to use it.

Comment: if your problem is just the scroll jerking, then just save the scroll position when a user updates the data and reset the scroll when the subscription fires

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Ty, I added `[ngForTrackBy]` to every and made a small function which returns the index. It didn´t worked directly but since some angular versions it started working like a charm. Still just overwritting the array but works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you control the event of leaf change inside the array, why not to switch values inside of array by position? You switch the values between `array[0][1][1][1]` and `array[0][1][2][2]` in the array and the `*ngFor` takes care of updating the view.

I dropped a simple plunkr [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/J808AhAft0G60gpdMpwC)

### Edit

If only the leafs change on your array and the elements of the main array remain 
on the same position, then you have an easy mission of comparing the elements by position and switch the elements as the leafs are different like:

```
//this assumes that main array won't change - same length and position
for (let i=0; i < originalArray.length; i++) {
  if (originalArray[i][leafindex] !== newArray[i][leafindex] {
    originalArray[i] = newArray[i];
  }
}
```

If the main array changes length or elements position, the implementation of comparison to look for the changes became difficult and prone to slow performance. In that case, I'll advise you to do it like you do now with rewriting the array, but take the scrollTop value before changing the data and apply the same scroll after the elements are re-rendered.

Comment: Hello first ty for your answer, this would work. But the problem is I load the new array via ajax and don't know which values have been changed. And if I move a object it does not just overwrite that key, it also deletes it from the previous position. Which results in moving all keys afterwards one key back.

Comment: sry for the late reply, your solution is fine but its missing an delete function for both sides. Still ty for your work.