# TrackBy reuse across nested ngFors (nested or 2d arrays)

Tags: angular, angular2-template

In the following example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/track-by-reuse?file=src/app/app.component.ts
if you change the number of columns from 4 to 3 the td elements with 1, 2, 3, 5, 6 and 9 are reused because of the trackBy functions but 4, 7, and 8 and re-rendered because they move from one tr element to the next.

Is there a way to track elements across nested ngFors? Could this be a feature request?

Example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45308735/6656422 doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to avoid using `table` and switch to CSS layout (bootstrap columns, maybe flexbox?), this way you will have only one loop and thus table will be rendered like simple list effectively using `trackBy`.

Comment: This is a workaround and I need a strict set of columns in markup.

Comment: `ngForOf` is only aware of its own components, there is no way to make two `ngForOf`'s aware of each other, the only way you have is to implement your own variation of `ngForOf` which can handle nested arrays.